# How can I connect an active subwoofer to my mixer recording set-up?

Tags: audio-interfaces, subwoofer, recorder-mixer

I have a Kustom 7250 I bought from a church that I am connecting to my Seinburg interface that is connected to my Acer desktop computer. I have 2 passive speakers, a small fender amp I am using as a monitor, and a Sony SAW subwoofer that only has a single input. How can I hook all of that together and record as well as listen live? Is it possible and what DAW would you recommend?

Comment: What do you want to listen to? The output of the mixer? Or the output of the computer? In your situation it seems more useful to have the speakers hooked to the output of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and ended up with a cheapo graphic EQ with a separate sub output. In my case it was the Behringer Ultrahraph Pro, but any similar will do.

In my setup the computer and ant instruments go into the interface, the interface outs are connected to the EQ which then sends left and right to my amp, and the sub out to my sub.